# expected unqualified-id before '->' token, How to fix this?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
struct box
{
    char word[200][200];
    char meaning[200][200];
    int count;
};

struct root {
    box *alphabets[26];
};
struct root *stem;
struct box *access;
void init(){
    int sizeofBox =  sizeof(struct box);
    for(int i = 0 ; i<= 25; i++){
        struct box *temp =(struct box*)( malloc(sizeofBox));
        temp->count = 0;
        root->alphabets[i] = temp; //error line
    }
}
```

> Error: Expected unqualified-id before '->' token

How to fix this bug.
Can anyone explain what kind is this...??

Comment: You probably meant `stem` instead of `root`, except that `stem` is never set to any value so that will crash at run-time. Maybe change `struct root* stem;` to `struct root stem;` (no pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root->alphabets[i] = temp;
```

Here `root` is a type. It no allowed to call `->` on a type. To use this operator, you must have a pointer to an instance.

I think this line should be:

```
   stem->alphabets[i] = temp;
// ^^^^
```

But you will have an error here because there is no memory allocated for it.

So this line:

```
struct root *stem;
```

should become

```
root *stem = /* ... */; // keyword "struct" is not need here in c++
```

Answer (score 1):

`root` is a type. You cannot call operator `->` on a type. You need a pointer to an instance (or an instance of a type that overloads `->`). You don't need to write `struct` all over the place in c++ either:

```
root* smth = ....; // look, no "struct"
smth->alphabets[0] = ....;
```

Note that this extensive use of raw pointers in C++ code is not idiomatic. You will run into other problems once you fix this one.

Comment: But I did with that '*stem' too. Error: expected primary expression before '->' token

Comment: @KarthikSivam Can you provide some minimal code that reproduces the problem (and doesn't include other, distracting errors?)