# Error in memory allocation for array of structures

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, malloc

I am working on this code:

```
struct box
{
    char word[200][200];
    char meaning[200][200];
    int count;
};

struct root {
    box *alphabets[26];
};
root *stem;
box *access;
void init(){
     //cout<<"start";
    for(int i = 0 ; i<= 25; i++){
        struct box *temp =(struct box*)( malloc(sizeof(struct box)*100));
        temp->count = 0;
        cout<<temp->count;
        stem->alphabets[i] = temp;
    }
    //cout<<" initialized";
}
```

It got compiled without errors, but during its execution it stops at the point where `temp` is allocated to `stem->alphabets[i]`. How to fix this?

Comment: `stem` is not initialized. Thus a crash. initialize `access` too.

Comment: are you using C or C++? They are different languages.

Comment: Why are you using malloc in a C++ program ???

Comment: Choose one C or C++ ? With C++, you have STL, to make you job lot easier.

Comment: Am I misreading? why `malloc(sizeof(struct box)*100)`? why *100?

Comment: [I told you you would run into more problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799680/expected-unqualified-id-before-token-how-to-fix-this/18799690#18799690) :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `stem` a `struct`, not a pointer:

```
root stem; // No asterisk
```

Otherwise, there's no memory allocated to it, so dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Of course you need to replace `stem->alphabets[i]` with `stem.alphabets[i]`.

Comment: You meant `stem` i guess.

Comment: @KarthikSivam You are welcome! If this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This lets other visitors of the site know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution to this problem, and earns you a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

You need to allocate memory for the `stem` variable

```
root * stem = new root();
```

Don't forget to dealocate:

```
delete stem;
```

Better yet, read something about [memory allocations](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/) in C++

Answer (score 3):

`stem` and `temp` are two different variables. :) you are giving memory to `temp` and accessing `stem`.

Comment: I am habitual of this :) carry on guyz

Comment: That was me -- although I'd swear the "you are giving memory to temp and accessing stem" wasn't there when I voted, it won't let me reverse until you edit. :(

Comment: Ok -- spoofed that with a dud edit to get this travesty off my conscience.  All apologies.

Comment: @goldilocks chill man, and thanks and salute to your honesty :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using pointers without initializing them first. The simple answer is **not to use pointers in the first place**. I can see no reason for pointers in the code you have posted.

```
struct box
{
    char word[200][200];
    char meaning[200][200];
    int count;
};

struct root {
    box alphabets[26];
};
root stem;
```

Much easier.